# Search for multiple strings in MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, string, search, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to do something like "reverse engineering". I have a CSV file which will be somewhere in database. I'm very very very new to SQL. I'd like to search for two strings from two different columns (of the same row) in order to locate it in the database. I know how to search for one string in many tables, but could anyone tell me how to search multiple strings. 
If you wish to down vote, please pass a useful comment and then do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE Column1 = "your string #1" AND Column2 = "your string #2";
```

for multiple tables..i am assuming you mean

```
 SELECT * FROM YourTable INNER JOIN YourTable2 ON YourTable1.xxx = YourTable2.xxx WHERE Column1 = "..." AND Column2 = "..." AND Column3 = "...";
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it out and will let you know.

Comment: It works. Is there a way I can do it on multiple tables with multiple strings?

Comment: Let's say I have 10 database connections and each one has multiple schemas in it. Is there a way I can search all the schemas in one database at once for these two strings?

Comment: By database I mean connections and tables are in it, if I make any sense.

Comment: @abn still don't understand, you mean 10 databases each with a table of the same schema or 1 database with 10 tables? I have included the wild guess in my answer. Can't do anything more unless you post the table schema